# How to calculate the number of each weekday between 2 dates in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

There is a column with dates. I would like to calculate the number of each weekday (Monday to Sunday) from those dates to present date. On Stack Overflow and otherwise, I found answers that included creating functions, I was hoping there's some inbuilt function that would do it. I found another solution [here](https://help.looker.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023861113-How-to-Count-Only-Weekdays-Between-Two-Dates), which mentions `DATEPART('day', start - stop) AS days`, but that didn't work. If this is an recent update in PostgreSQL then it won't work because the tool we use at work for PostgreSQL doesn't accept some of the recent updates (like PostgreSQL now accepts negative indexing but the tool doesn't).

What I want:

| start_date | day_of_week | no_of_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | 1 | 10 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2 | 9 |
| 2022-05-15 | 2 | 3 |
| 2022-06-01 | 5 | 1 |

The `start_date` is the column of dates, which when subtracted from `current_date` (the other way around) returns the number of each weekday between those two days. There were 10 Mondays between 1st April 2022 and 6th June 2022 (today), and that's the number I want for each day of the week.

How can I achieve this in PostgreSQL? I am on version 12.8.

Comment: Please provide your version of Postgres. (`SELECT version();`) And fix your data sample: the same date can't have different results. And fix your sentence: *"I would like to calculate the number of each weekday (Monday to Sunday) from that date to present date"* Doesn't make sense when I read it.

Comment: My data sample is correct. The results are different for the same date because the day of week for them is different. 1 is Monday, 2 is Tuesday. Between that date and today, there were 10 Mondays and 9 Tuesdays. Changed the other 2 things according to your suggestion.

Comment: day-of-week, this will be a surprise for you: SELECT EXTRACT(dow from '2022-04-01'::date); -- 5... In your example it's 1 and/or 2

Comment: So you want 7 result rows for every input row - one for each weekday? Lower and upper date bound are included / excluded?

Comment: Yes, I want 7 result rows. Lower bound is included, upper bound should ideally be excluded but it's fine if it's included.

Comment: Then my given answer is not what you wanted to ask for ... ?

Comment: Yes, I just realised it's not I want. Apologies. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This "simple" but optimized solution counts the number of occurrences for every weekday in the interval between `start_date` and the current date:

```sql
WITH cte(start_date) AS (
   VALUES
     ('2022-04-01'::date)
   , ('2022-05-15')
   , ('2022-06-01')
   )
SELECT c.start_date, sub.dow, sub.no_of_days
FROM   cte c
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT dow, COALESCE(ct, 0) AS no_of_days
   FROM  (
      SELECT EXTRACT('isodow' FROM g)::int AS dow, count(*) AS ct
      FROM   generate_series(start_date, current_date, interval '1 day') g
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) g
   RIGHT  JOIN generate_series(1, 7) dow USING (dow)
   ) sub
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5966b6765c1f504bc941dd697d71985d)*

The upper bound (`current_date`) is *included*.

Every weekday is included, even when `no_of_days` is 0.

For very old dates (resulting in long intervals), an arithmetic solution will be cheaper than simply counting generated days. A bit more challenging, but not that hard.

Comment: This gives me the number of Fridays (1st April was a Friday) between 1st April and today, I want the number of each day of week, Monday to Sunday, between 1st April and today.

Comment: I extended for every weekday.

Comment: So do you have your answer?